# Build Contacts Application using Android SDK

Tags: android

I am trying to build default Contacts application from Source code using Android SDK (i.e. Eclipse & ADT) as I wanted to add some more options into contact details (which are specific to my requirement). But it's giving me some compilation errors as android.jar is not having all the classes required to build this application.
Please tell me how can I achieve this.

Thanks, 
Parag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot build the "default Contacts application from Source code using Android SDK". You can only build that app as part of a complete custom firmware build.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Is there any other way to add some more fields into Contact details along with the defaults. OR Can I replace default Contacts application with my custom application.

Comment: @Parag: "Is there any other way to add some more fields into Contact details along with the defaults." -- not that I am aware of. For starters, the GUI will not be able to automatically adjust. "Can I replace default Contacts application with my custom application." -- not completely. You can arrange to be an option when, say, some app does an `ACTION_VIEW` on a contact. The user will have a choice of which app to use then.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But 3D Contacts application has done this, you can check following links, http://www.themobileindian.com/news/751_3D-Contact-app-on-Android-to-replace-default-contact-list and  https://market.android.com/details?id=AzureNightwalker.ContactList&feature=search_result  .If you can flash some light on this, it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: @Parag: That does not "add some more fields into Contact details along with the defaults". That does not "replace default Contacts application with my custom application". If you wish to write your own contact browser like this one, use `android.provider.ContactsContract`.